# How to check whether the function “App.ServisTanimId.getValue” exists as a property before calling it?

Tags: javascript, c#, extjs, ext.net

I have a JavaScript code in my CSHTML. When I click the button it runs a function. But in some windows `App.ServisTanimId.getValue()` is `undefined`. That’s why my button doesn’t work. Is there any way like to check if `App.ServisTanimId.getValue()` is undefined and only then do it?

```
Pencere = function(parameters) {
  Ext.net.directRequest({
    url: '@(Url.Action("window", "Home", new { Area = "area" }))',
    extraParams: {
      ServisTanimId: App.ServisTanimId.getValue(),
      CepDepoTanimId: App.CepDepoTanimId.getValue()
    },
    eventMask: {
      showMask: true
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(App.ServisTanimId) {
  // This code will execute if App.ServisTanimId is defined
} else {
  // If undefined
}
```

should work

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. Error is "TypeError: App.ServisTanimId is undefined" on Firebug.